# Set numberOfLines for specific UIAlertController (not all of them)

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I was having issues with text truncating with UIAlertController but that issue is fixed now with:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
```

This will set ALL UIAlertControllers to `numberOfLines = 2` but I only want this set to one specific UIAlertController.  How can I achieve this?

My actual code for the UIAlertController:

```swift
let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Location", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
for data in locationListArr {
    let displayName = "\(data.locAddr1 ?? "") \(data.locAddr2 ?? "") \(data.locCity ?? "") \(data.locProv ?? "") \(data.locPC ?? "")".uppercased()
    
    let item = UIAlertAction(title: displayName, style: .default) { (action) in
        self.locID = data.locID
        self.locName = data.locName ?? ""
        self.locAddr1 = data.locAddr1 ?? ""
        self.locAddr2 = data.locAddr2 ?? ""
        self.locCity = data.locCity ?? ""
        self.locProv = data.locProv ?? ""
        self.locPC = data.locPC ?? ""
        
        self.locationBtn.setTitle(displayName, for: .normal)
    }
    sheet.addAction(item)
}

present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
```

Comment: You're trying to add a series of action buttons with 2-line labels to your alert controller?

Comment: UIAlertController is not customizable. Use a custom presented view controller instead of the built-in alert controller. You can make it look and behave just like an alert controller's view if you want to. The difference is that you're in charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's docs say you shouldn't subclass `UIAlertController`, but I just tried it, and you can create an empty subclass of `UIAlertController`, and use `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)` on that subclass.

Take this example:

```
// Define a dummy subclass of `UIAlertController`
class FooController: UIAlertController {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let buttonLabels = [
    """
    Button1
    line2
    """,
    """
    Button2
    line2
    """,
    """
    Button3
    line2
    """
    ]

    @IBAction func handleAlertButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Invoke a normal UIAlertController
        presentAlert(type: UIAlertController.self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func handleFooButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Invoke a FooController.
        presentAlert(type: FooController.self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Tweak the appearance of UILabels in `FooController`s
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [FooController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
    }
    
    // This function invokes either a normal `UIAlertController` or a custom subclass of `UIAlertController`.
    func presentAlert(type: UIAlertController.Type) {
        let sheet = type.init(title: type.description(), message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            
        for buttonTitle in buttonLabels {
            
            let item = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .default) { (action) in
                print("Button \(buttonTitle) tapped")
            }
            sheet.addAction(item)
        }

        present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The `handleFooButton()` IBAction creates a `UIAlertController` with multi-line action titles, but the `handleAlertButton()` IBAction creates a normal `UIAlertController` where the actions have single-line titles. That proves that the line `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [FooController.self]).numberOfLines = 2` only sets the appearance of UILabels in the context of the dummy `FooController`. It **does not** prove that there are no adverse side-effects of ignoring the docs and subclassing `UIAlertController`.

Given that the subclass of `UIAlertController` is completely empty, and only defined in order to give a custom target to `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf)`, this **may** be safe. I say "may" because Apple explicitly says not to subclass `UIAlertController`, and you ignore explicit instructions like that from the docs at your own risk.

Given that risk, you are probably better off creating your own modal view controller that looks and acts like a `UIAlertController` (As matt suggests in his comment.) It's not that complicated.

Comment: I uploaded my demo project to Github. You can download it at the following link: https://github.com/DuncanMC/FooAlertController.git