# Is an empty subclass of UIAlertController safe for use with `appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)`

Tags: ios, uikit, uialertcontroller, subclassing

Somebody here on SO wanted to alter the behavior of `UIAlertAction` buttons in a specific `UIAlertController`, but not others. (They wanted multi-line button labels for one alert but normal behavior for all other alerts.) ([**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602012/set-numberoflines-for-specific-uialertcontroller-not-all-of-them) is a link to the other question.)

If you read the docs for `UIAlertController` it says that

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and doesn’t support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

As an experiment, I decided to try creating a dummy, empty subclass of `UIAlertController`, purely so that I had a class name to give to the `UIAppearance` method `appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)`

The definition of the dummy subclass is just this:

```
class FooController: UIAlertController {
}
```

That then lets me use the statement

```
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [FooController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
```

and override the appearance of `UILabel`s specifically in instances of`FooController`

It works, seemingly flawlessly.

The `FooController` creates an alert with 2-line button labels like this:

[image]

And the Vanilla `UIAlertController` creates an alert with 1-line button titles even though it gets passed 2 line titles:

[image]

You can download the sample project from Github [**here**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/FooAlertController.git).

When you create a vanilla `UIAlertController`, its `UIAlertAction` buttons have single-line labels as normal. When you create a `FooController`, its `UIAlertAction` buttons have multi-line labels.

While it seems to work perfectly, I am leery of going against an explicit statement in Apple's docs **not** to subclass `UIAlertController`.

What are the risks of ignoring that admonition and using an empty subclass?

Here is the code from my sample project for reference:

```
import UIKit

class FooController: UIAlertController {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let buttonLabels = [
    """
    Button1
    line2
    """,
    """
    Button2
    line2
    """,
    """
    Button3
    line2
    """
    ]

    @IBAction func handleAlertButton(_ sender: Any) {
        presentAlert(type: UIAlertController.self)
    }
    
    @IBAction func handleFooButton(_ sender: Any) {
        presentAlert(type: FooController.self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [FooController.self]).numberOfLines = 2
    }
    
    func presentAlert(type: UIAlertController.Type) {
        let sheet = type.init(title: type.description(), message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        for buttonTitle in buttonLabels {
            let item = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .default) { (action) in
                print("Button \(buttonTitle) tapped")
            }
            sheet.addAction(item)
        }
        present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've subclassed several of Apple's "do not subclass this class" classes for years and I've never had any issues. But I've also never done anything in those subclasses that attempt to modify the existing functionality or dig into private subviews. So I can't imagine there ever being an issue with your trivial subclass of UIAlertController.

Comment: Yeah, I _very_ often use the trick of subclassing something merely to give it a distinctive class name, so who am I to judge? :)

Comment: The only time I have ever subclassed one of the classes "that does not support subclassing" was to interrogate the functionality of the API.  The subclass did not change the function, but executed debugging statements (or used break points), so I could understand what was happening. This was usually due to poor Apple documentation.

Comment: I should also point out that we are starting to see Swift only APIs from Apple, that use the keyword Final to prevent subclassing of a given class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What are the risks of ignoring that admonition and using an empty subclass?*

1. Apple might reject the app.
2. The `UIAlertController` might not function correctly in a future update of iOS.
3. The specific reason (using `UILabel.appearance`) for the subclass might not function correctly in a future update of iOS.

Those are the possible risks.

While Apple always has the final say, it's highly unlikely that Apple would reject an app simply because you subclassed `UIAlertController` in such a manner. I've personally subclassed several UIKit classes that Apple says should not be subclassed. I've done this in an app that has been in the app store for many years and has had many updates. You are not using any private APIs. And Apple does not say that you can't subclass `UIAlertController`. It says that the class isn't intended to be subclassed.

This leads to risk #2. Apple states that `UIAlertController` isn't intended to be subclassed and it doesn't support subclassing. This means that it does not provide any API that is meant to be overridden or modified. But it does not mean that you can't subclass it to add helper methods, for example. Or simply to give the class a new name such that you can do things like your `UILabel.appearance`. Your subclass is benign and makes no attempt to modify the functionality or dig into the private subview structure. It's a "safe" subclass that won't break any existing functionality.

Lastly, risk #3. While minor, this is probably the "biggest" risk of the 3. Apple could make any number of changes to `UIAlertController` in a future update to iOS that might hinder or break the desired result of using `UILabel.appearance` on your subclass. Testing the code on every release of iOS would be prudent. Likely, the worst case will be that the "hack" will stop working.

Comment: That's a nice, thorough description of the possible risks, and lines up pretty well with my thinking. Thanks.

Comment: A minor point: Using `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:)` to modify the `UIAlertController` is probably a little fragile, as you say. I'm not sure tweaking the alert in a subclass makes the tweak *more* fragile than doing it on all `UIAlertController`s however.

Comment: @DuncanC Certainly the best approach is for the original asker to create their own custom alert class that does exactly what they want (as other comments on that other question point out). I admit my answer is more focused on the risks of extending `UIAlertController` and less so on the validity of using `UILabel.appearance` and the `UIAlertController` subclass to achieve something the alert doesn't otherwise provide an API for.

Comment: Understood. My question was focused on the use of an empty subclass simply to tie the appearance proxy to a **specific** alert controller.